# C++ How can i erase a char from a string (input)

Tags: c++, string, erase

I am trying to make a program although i have finished it already i need something more. So, the user asked to give an input IF the string contains  *  i want to erase the first  *  and cout the input

```
    getline(cin,str);
    int k=str.length();
    for(int i=0; i<=k; i++)
        if(str[i]=='*')
            string::iterator it;
            it=str.begin()+i;
            str.erase(it);
            break;
    cout<<str<<endl;
```

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try if(str[i] == '*'). Also, add curly braces after if until the end of the stuff you want to be executed only if the statement is true.

Comment: Use [`str.find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to locate the `*` and there is version of `str.erase()` that accepts an index and length which avoids the iterator calculation.

Comment: Also, why not use the find method instead of looping through each character?  It should be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Be very careful, you need to use brackets `{}` to control scope, not tabulation!

Also, using `=` in a `if` is an assignation, not a check, you need to use `==`

You iterate using `i` yet you delete using `x`?

Comment: now scope your code with brackets and change `if(str[i]='*')` for `if(str[i]=='*')` and it should work

Comment: by scope I mean that you should have a leading `{` before the content of your if and `}` at the end of it

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this by using `std::find` to remove the first occurrence of `*`:

```
str.erase(std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), '*'));
```